# Including Css in jsf

Tags: html, css, jsf

This is my project structure:

[image]

I am going to add `css` file into `HeaderTester.xhtml` file:

This is `HeaderTester.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Here is header</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerStyle.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        This is Header tester class
        <div id="header">
            <h3>Sajjad HTlo</h3>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Css File:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

h1{
    color: silver;
}
```

But just displays texts in result!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415/1391249

Comment: @Tiny thanks for the link, thats a very detailed explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your `XML namespaces` declaration, you are using JSF 2.2.

Since JSF 2.0, you can place CSS, JavaScript files and images(and other files) into a *resources* directory in the root of your web application.

[image: css]

Then, you can include your CSS using the `h:outputStylesheet` :

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
```

Comment: So there is no need to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerStyle.css"/>` . Correct?

Comment: @SajjadHTLO No you will not need it, the `h:outputStylesheet` will generate a tag of this form: `<link href="/context-root/faces/javax.faces.resource/styles.css?ln=css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` to the header of your page